# Removing a single product from the cart in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm currently trying to create a view that allows you to remove a single item from the cart in Django. I've got a view that allows you to add a single product to the cart, but I'm having no luck creating a view that allows you to remove a single product.

FYI, I'm using Django version 1.

**This is my 'add_to_cart' view**:

```
def add_to_cart(request, id)

    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart[id] = cart.get(id, 1)

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(reverse('products'))
```

**This is my 'remove_from_cart' view (that doesn't work)**:

```
def remove_from_cart(request, id):

    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart[id] = cart.get(id, 0)

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(reverse('view_cart'))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it with `pop`:

```
def remove_from_cart(request, id):

    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart.pop(id, None)

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(reverse('view_cart'))
```

or if you want to decrement the number:

```
def remove_from_cart(request, id):
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart[id] = max(0, cart.get(id, 0) - 1)
    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(reverse('view_cart'))
```

Comment: Ahh brilliant. Thanks for your help!